# "Class 'CustomProfile' can't define method 'createState' and have field 'StatefulWidget.createState with the same name

Tags: flutter

**you can see my screen there**
[image: you can see my screen there]
I didn't have this problem before, but today, I wanted to create another page.dart in addition to my main.dart but it didn't work. So I cancelled everything I had put in and then I found that I had this error in my main.dart. Even when I open another project I have this error when I put the StatefulWidget on VS code or Android Studio please help me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that you just put a '_' in front of the states name.

This underscore marks the State as private but does not change its name.

Try to name the State something like 'CustomProfileState'.

Example:

```
class CustomProfile extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   CustomProfileState createState() => CustomProfileState();
}

class CustomProfileState extends State<CustomProfile> {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I still have the same issues

Comment: I edited my answer, please see the new one

Comment: nothing's changed, i posted my screen check it plz

Comment: This isn't true, `CustomProfile` and `_CustomProfile` are considered different classes. The underscore marks the class as private **and** makes the class differs from the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Even when I open another project, I've still the same issues [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azfiQ.png)

Comment: Well then try restart you IDE. Did you try it like I said? Because if yes maybe its a bug or something

Comment: Try it like this and say if the error still exists:

class CustomProfile extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   CustomProfileState createState() => CustomProfileState();
}

class CustomProfileState extends State<CustomProfile> {
   ...
}

Comment: same errors , should i uninstall flutter & dart on my PC ?

Comment: Try the command 'flutter clean' and then after it 'flutter pub get' and see if the error still persists. Maybe you try run 'flutter analyze'?

Comment: I've tried 'flutter clean' and then 'flutter pub get' and the error still persists.

Comment: What version of flutter are you using? Can you try upgrading it?

Comment: flutter 3.3.0 i use,  I run 'flutter upgrade', and I got  : Your flutter checkout has local changes that would be erased by upgrading. If you want to keep these changes, it is recommended that you stash them via "git
stash" or else commit the changes to a local branch. If it is okay to remove local changes, then re-run this command with "--force".

Comment: Maybe you upgrade to flutter 3.3.1?

Comment: When I run 'flutter upgrade', and I got  : Your flutter checkout has local changes that would be erased by upgrading. If you want to keep these changes, it is recommended that you stash them via "git
stash" or else commit the changes to a local branch. If it is okay to remove local changes, then re-run this command with "--force".

Comment: That means you have made changes to this file: <FlutterRoot>/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle If you dont need these changes, I would run the command 'flutter upgrade --force' since edits to flutter files can cause some problems like this. Then you should have a clean install of Flutter again

Comment: okay i will run 'flutter upgrade --force' and then i'll tell you

Comment: Does the problem still persist?

Comment: has been solved ty

Comment: This is not an "answer"! This is added information to the question. It is better if you put such added information as an "Edit" in the question itself.  Please do so, and delete this answer, thank you!