# State<WelcomePage> createState() => _WelcomePageState(); }

Tags: flutter

im new to coding/flutter/dart and im trying to pick things up as im going along. im trying to build a welcome page for an app. All is well until I try to add functionality to a show password field. the error is that the names are conflicting. How do I get around this issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome Page',
      home: WelcomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class WelcomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<WelcomePage> createState() => _WelcomePageState();
}

class _WelcomePageState extends State<WelcomePage> {
  bool _passwordVisible = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red[900], // Dark red     background
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            // ... other widgets ...

            // Password field
            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,     // Narrower width
              child: TextField(
                obscureText: !_passwordVisible, // Toggle     visibility
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Password',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  filled: true,
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      // Change the icon based on the     visibility state
                      _passwordVisible ? Icons.visibility :     Icons.visibility_off,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _passwordVisible = !_passwordVisible;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                 ),
              ),
            ),

            // ... other widgets ...
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Class 'WelcomePage' can't define method 'createState' and have field 'StatefulWidget.createState' with the same name.
Try converting the method to a getter, or renaming the method to a name that doesn't conflict.dart(conflicting_method_and_field)

this is the full code for the welcome page, and just above is the error. Can anyone identify why this happens and what the remedy is for this page and future pages if this kind of thing happens again.

Comment: This is not clear enough. Add the complete widget code and state the problem clearly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Class 'CustomProfile' can't define method 'createState' and have field 'StatefulWidget.createState with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73691210/class-customprofile-cant-define-method-createstate-and-have-field-statefu)

Comment: This question is a duplicate of the question I linked above, however that question still does not have a proper answer yet. Some of the comments suggest that it could be a problem with the Flutter version, so you might want to include the output of running `flutter doctor` in the post.

Comment: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on macOS 14.3 23D5043d darwin-arm64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!

Answer (score 0):

Delete this page and create a new with just typing stful. [image]

After that run on terminal **flutter pub clean** and wait to complete the process and then **flutter pub get**

You all oK :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what am I changing to stful and do you know why this error is occurring?